# How to fetch a binary file from a remote embeded system using telnet?

Tags: ruby, telnet

I have a remote embedded system and it is telnet-able. How can I fetch a binary file from it using ruby? If it were a text file, I could have used:

```
  con = Net::Telnet::new("Host"=>ip,"Timeout"=>200)  #Host not host
  File.open("fetched_file","w+") do |f|
        con.cmd("cat /ect/file")  {|data| f.write(data)}
  end
```

But this wouldn't work for binary file you won't get desirable data by `cat`ing it.

Comment: Telnet in and start the ftp daemon. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

establish your telnet connection then
send the command:

```
uuencode filename -
```

to the remote host, replacing filename with the filename

take the data you are sent and pass it to `uudecode` on your system

Answer (score 1):

If the device has `uuencode` installed, you could use that to 'wrap' the binary into printable characters. Other possibility is to run `dd if=/etc/file 2>/dev/null` to dump the data (however I am not completely certain this will word any better...)