# push file to remote system through telent using ruby

Tags: ruby, telnet

I have a remote embedded system which it is telnet-able. How can I download a binary file from the host to it? I [can read file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062834/how-to-fetch-a-binary-file-from-a-remote-embeded-system-using-telnet) from the system, but have no idea how to write to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably want to do this with [ftp](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/index.html)

If there is no ftp server on the target system try using [kermit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kermit%5F%28protocol%29)

Comment: unfortunately, The embedded system has no ftp server.